# Kinesis input stream into Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-kinesis

I am currently evaluating Logstash for our data ingestion needs. One of the use case is to read data from AWS Kinesis stream. I have tried to install logstash-input-kinesis plugin. When i run it, i do not see logstash processing any event from the stream. My logstash is working fine with other type of inputs (tcp). There is no error in debug logs. It just behaves as there is nothing to process. my config file is :

```
input {
    kinesis {
        kinesis_stream_name => "GwsElasticPoc"
        application_name => "logstash"
        type => "kinesis"
    }
    tcp {
         port => 10000
         type => tcp
    }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "kinesis" {
        json {
            source => "message"
        }  
    }

    if [type] == "tcp" {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "Hello, %{WORD:name}"}
        }
    }
} 

output{
    if [type] == "kinesis"
    {
        elasticsearch{
            hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
            user => "elastic"
            password => "changeme"
            index => elasticpoc
        }
    }
    if [type] == "tcp"
    {
        elasticsearch{
            hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
            user => "elastic"
            password => "changeme"
            index => elkpoc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried the logstash way but if you are running on AWS. There is a Kinesis Firehose to Elasticsearch ingestion available as documented at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-create.html#console-to-es

You can see if that would work as an alternate to logstash

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dejavu013. We have to ingest data from multiple sources (including Kinesis stream) so we are looking for something which can handle this. Converting all sources of data into kinesis stream is not an option right now.

Answer (score 0):

we need to provide the AWS credentials for accessing the AWS services for this integration to work.

You can find the same here: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-kinesis#authentication

Answer (score 0):

This plugin requires additional access to AWS DynamoDB as 'checkpointing' database.

You need to use 'application_name' to specify the table name in DynamoDB if you have multiple streams.

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-kinesis